# Vue 3 / Pinia / Reactive not updating correctly

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity, pinia

I am unable to retrieve the correct value of a pinia store property while subscribing to a store.

The following screenshot demonstrates my confusion.
Why i am unable to retrieve the updated value of `lastMutation`?

[image: debug_console]

> The update that triggers the `store.$subscribe`, is an update to `lastMutation` from 0 to 1668671191642.

I am expecting that `state.lastMutation` should be 1668671191642 and not 0.

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. We were hitting a bug, where a `$subscribe` is missing mutations after a `$patch` is performed.

Adding, `sync: true` to the subscription fixes the issue.

https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/992